# Dynamic sql execution issue sql server

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

i have construct a dynamic sql and it is bit big. so when i am trying to execute it then i am getting error like

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_InstallListenerNotification_1, Line 31
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_InstallListenerNotification_1, Line 118
Incorrect syntax near 'END'.
```

i am not being able to find out where is the problem and where to fix. so help me to compile it if possible. here is my dynamic sql script.

```
        DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @crlf CHAR(1)
        SET @crlf = CHAR(10)
        SET @msg = 'Current user must have following permissions: '
        SET @msg = @msg + '[CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE SERVICE, CREATE QUEUE, SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS, CONTROL, REFERENCES] '
        SET @msg = @msg + 'that are required to start query notifications. '
        SET @msg = @msg + 'Grant described permissions with following script: ' + @crlf
        SET @msg = @msg + 'GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO [<username>];' + @crlf
        SET @msg = @msg + 'GRANT CREATE SERVICE TO [<username>];' + @crlf
        SET @msg = @msg + 'GRANT CREATE QUEUE  TO [<username>];' + @crlf
        SET @msg = @msg + 'GRANT REFERENCES ON CONTRACT::[DEFAULT] TO [<username>];' + @crlf
        SET @msg = @msg + 'GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO [<username>];' + @crlf
        SET @msg = @msg + 'GRANT CONTROL ON SCHEMA::[<schemaname>] TO [<username>];'

        PRINT @msg

    IF OBJECT_ID ('[bba-reman].sp_InstallListenerNotification_1', 'P') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        EXEC ('
            CREATE PROCEDURE [bba-reman].sp_InstallListenerNotification_1
            AS
            BEGIN
                -- Service Broker configuration statement.

    -- Setup Service Broker
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases 
                        WHERE name = ''bbareman'' AND (is_broker_enabled = 0 OR is_trustworthy_on = 0)) 
    BEGIN
         IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.fn_my_permissions(NULL, ''SERVER'')
                                 WHERE permission_name = ''CONTROL SERVER''))
         BEGIN
            DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(MAX)
            SET @msg = ''Current user doesn''''t have CONTROL SERVER permission to enable service broker. ''
            SET @msg = @msg + ''Grant sufficient permissions to current user or ''
            SET @msg = @msg + ''execute ALTER DATABASE [<dbname>] SET ENABLE_BROKER with admin rights.''

            RAISERROR (@msg, 16, 1)
         END
         ELSE 
         BEGIN
            --ALTER DATABASE [bbareman] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
            --ALTER DATABASE [bbareman] SET ENABLE_BROKER; 
            --ALTER DATABASE [bbareman] SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

            -- FOR SQL Express
            --ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[bbareman] TO [sa]
            --ALTER DATABASE [bbareman] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;               
         END
    END

    -- Create a queue which will hold the tracked information 
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_queues WHERE name = ''ListenerQueue_1'')
        CREATE QUEUE [bba-reman].[ListenerQueue_1]
    -- Create a service on which tracked information will be sent 
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.services WHERE name = ''ListenerService_1'')
        CREATE SERVICE [ListenerService_1] ON QUEUE [bba-reman].[ListenerQueue_1] ([DEFAULT]) 


                -- Notification Trigger check statement.

    IF OBJECT_ID (''[bba-reman].tr_Listener_1'', ''TR'') IS NOT NULL
        RETURN;


                -- Notification Trigger configuration statement.
                DECLARE @triggerStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
                DECLARE @select NVARCHAR(MAX)
                DECLARE @sqlInserted NVARCHAR(MAX)
                DECLARE @sqlDeleted NVARCHAR(MAX)

                SET @triggerStatement = N''
    CREATE TRIGGER [tr_Listener_1]
    ON [bba-reman].[ContentChangeLog]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
    AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Trigger ContentChangeLog is rising...
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.services WHERE name = ''''ListenerService_1'''')
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @message NVARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @message = N''''<root/>''''

        IF ( EXISTS(SELECT 1))
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @retvalOUT NVARCHAR(MAX)

            %inserted_select_statement%

            IF (@retvalOUT IS NOT NULL)
            BEGIN SET @message = N''''<root>'''' + @retvalOUT END                        

            %deleted_select_statement%

            IF (@retvalOUT IS NOT NULL)
            BEGIN
                IF (@message = N''''<root/>'''') BEGIN SET @message = N''''<root>'''' + @retvalOUT END
                ELSE BEGIN SET @message = @message + @retvalOUT END
            END 

            IF (@message != N''''<root/>'''') BEGIN SET @message = @message + N''''</root>'''' END
        END

        --Beginning of dialog...
        DECLARE @ConvHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
        --Determine the Initiator Service, Target Service and the Contract 
        BEGIN DIALOG @ConvHandle 
            FROM SERVICE [ListenerService_1] TO SERVICE ''''ListenerService_1'''' ON CONTRACT [DEFAULT] WITH ENCRYPTION=OFF, LIFETIME = 60; 
        --Send the Message
        SEND ON CONVERSATION @ConvHandle MESSAGE TYPE [DEFAULT] (@message);
        --End conversation
        END CONVERSATION @ConvHandle;
    END
''

                SET @select = STUFF((SELECT '','' + COLUMN_NAME
                                     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                     WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''ContentChangeLog'' AND TABLE_CATALOG = ''bbareman''
                                     FOR XML PATH ('''')
                                     ), 1, 1, '''')
                SET @sqlInserted = 
                    N''SET @retvalOUT = (SELECT '' + @select + N'' 
                                         FROM INSERTED 
                                         FOR XML PATH(''''row''''), ROOT (''''inserted''''))''
                SET @sqlDeleted = 
                    N''SET @retvalOUT = (SELECT '' + @select + N'' 
                                         FROM DELETED 
                                         FOR XML PATH(''''row''''), ROOT (''''deleted''''))''                            
                SET @triggerStatement = REPLACE(@triggerStatement
                                         , ''%inserted_select_statement%'', @sqlInserted)
                SET @triggerStatement = REPLACE(@triggerStatement
                                         , ''%deleted_select_statement%'', @sqlDeleted)

                EXEC sp_executeSql @triggerStatement
            END
            ')
    END
```

Comment: Why does it need to be dynamic? I can't see anywhere in the script where you include any kind of variables from outside.

Comment: You have a `BEGIN...END` with everything in between commented out...

Comment: the above sql was constructed by some one else. i saw this line `%inserted_select_statement% ` in sql and do not understand what it is ? anyone can guide me about this syntax in sql `%inserted_select_statement% `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have an empty `BEGIN ...END` block. You need to add at least one executable statement, for example a `PRINT`

```
 BEGIN
     --ALTER DATABASE [bbareman] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
     --ALTER DATABASE [bbareman] SET ENABLE_BROKER; 
     --ALTER DATABASE [bbareman] SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

    -- FOR SQL Express
    --ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[bbareman] TO [sa]
    --ALTER DATABASE [bbareman] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON; 

     PRINT 'Dummy Output'

     END
```

It also looks like you are missing an `END`. You need three `END` statements after the dummy `PRINT`.

Comment: the above sql was constructed by some one else. i saw this line `%inserted_select_statement% ` in sql and do not understand what it is ? anyone can guide me about this syntax in sql `%inserted_select_statement% `